# aws_ecs_cluster local-exec aws not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, command, amazon-ecs

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "demo" {
  name = var.ecs_cluster_name

  capacity_providers = [local.cluster_name]

  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = local.cluster_name
  }
  # We need to terminate all instances before the cluster can be destroyed.
  # (Terraform would handle this automatically if the autoscaling group depended
  #  on the cluster, but we need to have the dependency in the reverse
  #  direction due to the capacity_providers field above).
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOT
      set -e
      CAP_PROVS="$(aws ecs describe-clusters --clusters "${self.arn}" \
        --query 'clusters[*].capacityProviders[*]' --output text)"

      ASG_ARNS="$(aws ecs describe-capacity-providers \
        --capacity-providers "$CAP_PROVS" \
        --query 'capacityProviders[*].autoScalingGroupProvider.autoScalingGroupArn' \
        --output text)"

      if [ -n "$ASG_ARNS" ] && [ "$ASG_ARNS" != "None" ]
      then
        for ASG_ARN in $ASG_ARNS
        do
          ASG_NAME=$(echo $ASG_ARN | cut -d/ -f2-)

          aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group \
            --auto-scaling-group-name "$ASG_NAME" \
            --min-size 0 --max-size 0 --desired-capacity 0

          INSTANCES="$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
            --auto-scaling-group-names "$ASG_NAME" \
            --query 'AutoScalingGroups[*].Instances[*].InstanceId' \
            --output text)"
          aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --instance-ids $INSTANCES \
            --auto-scaling-group-name "$ASG_NAME" \
            --no-protected-from-scale-in
        done
      fi
    EOT
  }
}
```

aws_ecs_service local-exec not working and the error say aws command not found

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11409

Error: Error deleting ECS cluster: ClusterContainsContainerInstancesException: The Cluster cannot be deleted while Container InstancesainsContainerInstancesException: The Cluster cantainer Instances are actnot be deleted while Container Instances are active or draining

Error waiting for internet gateway (igw 'detached' (last state:-0e21e59722a46f970) to detach: timeout while waiting for state to become 'detached' (last state: 'detaching', timeout: 15m0s)

aws_ecs_cluster.demo (local-exec): /bin/bash: aws: command not found

Comment: Do you have `aws` installed?

Comment: @Marcin
 Yes My window host computer has aws cli version 2 

PS C:\Users\dell> aws --version
aws-cli/1.20.44 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.21.44

Comment: aws.exe is in C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin

Comment: So you have `bash` on Windows?

Comment: PS C:\Users\dell> bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Yes I have bash too

Comment: If I delete     interpreter = ["bash", "-c"] , 

aws_ecs_cluster.demo (local-exec): 'CAP_PROVS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
aws_ecs_cluster.demo (local-exec): operable program or batch file

this occur

Comment: If you have aws cli installed, why are you using `bash`? can't you simply use  `interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]` and `aws x,y,z`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. It looks like an issue with aws provider. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11409

Comment: aws_ecs_cluster.demo (local-exec): At line:9 char:9
aws_ecs_cluster.demo (local-exec): +       if [ -n "$ASG_ARNS" ] && [ "$ASG_ARNS" != "None" ]
aws_ecs_cluster.demo (local-exec): +         ~
aws_ecs_cluster.demo (local-exec): Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.

This error happens if I use ["PowerShell", "-Command"]

Comment: You can't just run a bash script in powershell. Your options are either to adapt this script to run as powershell, or adapt your bash environment to run the aws cli. If you run `bash` in your host, then run `which aws` is one found? I assume not. Make aws available to the bash environment.

Comment: Ah so I downloaded aws on bash too via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html. And
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DescribeClusters operation: Unsupported resource type: cluster what this mean..?
If I type the same code on bash, it works. But in terraform local-exec it not working